# HTML element turned into event after being passed into Promise reject function

Tags: javascript

Something really weird is happening.  I'm passing an HTML element into the Reject function of a Promise, and after passing it in, it turns into an Event object.  Why?

```
<img class="lazy-image" data-src="http://example.com/photo" id='img'>

var photo = document.getElementById('img');
console.log(photo); // This returns an Element.
PhotoCheck(photo).then(function() {}, function(photo) {
    console.log(photo); // This returns an Event object in my console.  Why?
}

function photoCheck(img) {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            img.onload = resolve
            img.onerror = reject
            img.setAttribute("src", img.getAttribute("data-src"));
            img.classList.remove('lazy-image');
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: "*I'm passing an HTML element into the Reject function*" - uh, no? You're not even calling `reject` yourself. You install it as an `error` event listener, and of course that will get called with an event.

Comment: @Bergi How can I call the `reject` directly?  I don't see how the installing it as an error event can completely change the type of element from an HTML element to an event.

Comment: Not sure that's where your confusion stems from, but you have multiple variables named `img` in your code (one declared as `var`, two declared as function parameters). You might want to change them into three distinct names.

Comment: @Bergi After I changed my variables, a HTML element passed into `then()`'s fail function is still being turned into an event.

Comment: Well, no, it's not passed in. Could you please [edit] your post to update the names, then I can explain in detail?

Comment: @Bergi I have edited the question.  Thank you for your patience

Comment: `img.onload = resolve.bind(null, img);` and `img.onerror = reject.bind(null, img);`

Comment: You're not even calling `photoCheckLazy`.

Comment: @melpomene Sorry that was a copy and paste mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still have two different variables with the name `photo`:

```
var photo = document.getElementById('img'); /*
^^^^^^^^^ */
PhotoCheck(photo).then(function() {}, function(photo) {
//                                             ^^^^^
});
```

Let's be explicit and name everything differently:

```
var photo = document.getElementById('img');
PhotoCheck(photo).then(function(result) {}, function(error) {
    console.log(error, photo);
});

function photoCheck(img) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        img.onload = function(loadEvent) { resolve(loadEvent); };
        img.onerror = function(errorEvent) { reject(errorEvent); };
        img.setAttribute("src", img.getAttribute("data-src"));
        img.classList.remove('lazy-image');
    })
}
```

It is hopefully clear now that `photo` and `img` are the same value, referring to the DOM element. The promise however is rejected with the `errorEvent` which gets then passed to the `error` parameter of your rejection callback. Those are different things!

If you want to refer to the DOM element in the rejection handler, you either need to change your log statement to use `photo` instead of `error`, or you need to change the `photoCheck` function and call `reject` with `img` instead of `errorEvent` (which doesn't make much sense though).

Answer (score 1):

You are passing photo as a argument which will be passed when reject is called. And reject pass event for it. See what I have done

```js
var photo = document.getElementById('img');
console.log(photo); // This returns an Element.
PhotoCheck(photo).then(function() {}, function() {
    console.log(photo); // This returns an Event object in my console.  Why?
})

function PhotoCheck(img) {
    return new Promise(
        function(resolve, reject) {
            img.onload = resolve
            img.onerror = reject
            img.setAttribute("src", img.getAttribute("data-src"));
            img.classList.remove('lazy-image');
        }
    )
}
```

```html
<img class="lazy-image" data-src="http://example.com/photo" id='img'>
```